# PyCharm and PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a directory that I use for my `PYTHONPATH`: `c:\test\my\scripts\`. In this directory, I have some modules I import. It works well in my Python shell.

How do I add this directory path to PyCharm, so I can import what is in that directory?

Comment: "You need to go to the Main PyCharm Preferences, which will ...." There is no longer such things as "Main PyCharm" or "Preferences" in 2018.1.4 Community Edition, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947494/add-directory-to-python-path-in-pycharm

Answer (score 188):

> *Out of date. See Duane's answer below for pycharm version newer than 2019.2.*

You need to go to the *Main PyCharm* **Preferences**, which will open up a separate window. In the left pane, choose **Project:...** > **Project Interpreter**. Now, in the main pane on the right, click the settings symbol (gear symbol) next to the field for "Project Interpreter". Choose **More** or **Show All** in the menu that pops up. Now in the final step, pick the interpreter you are using for this project and click on the tree symbol at the bottom of the window (hovering over the symbol reveals it as "Show paths for the selected interpreter"). Add your path by click in the "plus" symbol.

It took me ages to find, so I hope the detailed instructions will help. Further details are available in the [PyCharm docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/installing-uninstalling-and-reloading-interpreter-paths.html?search=add%20folder%20to%20path).

It is good practice to have `__init__.py` in each subfolder of the module you are looking to add, as well as making your project folder a 'Source Root'. Simply right-click on the folder in the path bar and choose 'Mark Directory as ...'

Comment: There is no longer a **More** entry.  Now there is **Add Local...**.  Not sure of the next step. (Pycharm 2017.3.3 on MacOS)

Comment: Instead of the **More** entry, which doesn't exist anymore, you should now click on **Show All...** once you are in the project interpreter page and click on the settings icon.

Comment: Any suggestions for folks using Intellij with Python plugin?

Comment: Works like charm! Though it's weird that CLion uses this way of assigning paths to look for modules in. PYTHONPATH seems to be more trivial and known to everybody...

Answer (score 103):

For Pycharm Community 2019.3

- File
- Settings
- Project
- Project Interpreter
- Cog in top right => Show all
- Select the interpreter
- On the right toolbar, there are 5 icons, bottom one looks like a folder tree, [image: folder tree]click it
- Press plus +
- Select directory, press OK

Comment: PyCharm 2018/03: there is no "folder tree" icon.

Comment: Added the icon for clarity.  From 2018.3.5

Comment: In current version (2019.3.1) the cogwheel is in position "top right".

Comment: Where is the config file that storing such information?

Comment: no such icon anymore (2021.3.3 pro)... how was this dialog called?

Comment: For me on PyCharm 2022.2.1 (community, installed via snap) this setting was located in File > Settings > Project > Python Interpreter > Dropdown > Show All > Then the little folder tree icon top left for your interpreter.

Answer (score 59):

In PyCharm Community 2019.2/2019.3 (and probably other versions), you can simply:

- right-click any folder in your project
- select "Mark Directory As"
- select "Sources Root"

Modules within that folder will now be available for import. Any number of folders can be so marked.

Comment: What about a local package which isn't part of the project? What would be the implications of including this foreign directory in the project and marking it as "Sources Root"?

Comment: @YvesgereY Assuming you can see the directory in the first place (can you?) I don't see a problem with that. So far as I know, 'Sources Root' doesn't have any special meaning but to use that directory for resolving imports

Comment: Excellent. This helped me in no time.
(I have a large project where Pythonic project is in `src/build` and have to be added to PYTHONPATH or Sources Root to view in Pycharm).

Comment: this solution works, interpreter settings is the wrong place to look

Answer (score 25):

The following answer is for PyCharm 2022.1.3+ (Professional Edition).

1. Open up **Preferences** (mac: `⌘` + `,`)
   [image]
2. Click on **Project** and then **Project Interpreter**
   [image]
3. Click on the **three vertical dots** and the on **Show All...**

[image]
[image]

4. Choose your interpreter and then click on the directory structure icon
   [image]
5. Click on the `+` icon and add the path you need to add to `PYTHONPATH`.
   [image]

That's it!

Comment: Thank you!   I have no idea why JetBrains would make it this hard for something that is so routinely needed.   Also, as of version 2022.2.3, "Preferences" is now called, "Settings."

Answer (score 0):

As of PyCharm 2023.3.3, adding `PYTHONPATH=foo:bar:baz` to the "Environment Variables" section of a "Run Configuration" does not work. One must go to the "Project Structure" item under the "Project: foobar" item in the "Settings Dialog" and "Add Content Root," e.g. [image: Add Content Root panel].

Comment: I would recommend @Imiguelvargasf's approach instead to configure it on the interpreter level instead of the project level.