# PYTHONPATH set but not added to sys.path

Tags: python-3.x, package, sys.path

I've got a Chromebook running Ubutu. I just created my own package I need my programs to access. I got it all working on Mac OSX last night, and the source code is all the same. There is an init.py file (with underscores!) in the package directory. I have tried setting PYTHONPATH in both my .bashrc and .profile. I echo it to the terminal, and it displays the right directory for my package. But when I run Python and look at sys.path, the directory has not been added to sys.path! I did all these same steps on Mac OSX last night, and saw the new dir show up fine in sys.path.

Comment: By the way, both computers are running python 3.4 and the most recent anaconda distribution.

Comment: Fixed: On Mac OSX I did not need to export the shell variable. Apparently this is necessary on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the similar question, but mine is [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), not the anaconda. I just add the path in PyCharm [interpreters configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326362/pycharm-and-pythonpath),then it works. I don't know if the anaconda have the similar settings. I hope it works for you.