# Cannot Import MySQLdb in PyCharm, runs fine in terminal.

Tags: python, import, ide, pycharm, mysql-python

I have problems trying to run a script which imports MySQLdb within PyCharm.
Running the script from terminal works just fine while running within PyCharm fails with

```
ImportError: No module named MySQLdb
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383310/python-mysqldb-library-not-loaded-libmysqlclient-18-dylib) thread and it helped making things work in the terminal.
Trying to set the environment variables in the IDE though does not seem to work.
In PyCharm Run Config I set the environment variables

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH - /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
PATH - /usr/local/mysql/lib/
```

but I still get the ImportError.

Comment: One trick with these IDEs is often to start them in an already rightfully prepared environment (that is from terminal) as these settings are magically considered then ...

Comment: I’ve already tried but the problem persists.

Comment: Did you see `MySQLdb` in **Project Interpreter**?

Comment: Ok the most important path for python when it comes to import search paths is ... `PYTHONPATH` you should inspect that and validate this includes the path to your module (because the error states that there is no such module upon import)

Comment: @julivico you are right. can’t find it in the Project Interpreter. Trying to add it I have mysqldbhelper, raisin.mysqldb, umysqldb... Which one should I pick? Also, I already installed mysqldb using pip, it works fine when calling scripts from the terminal.

Comment: @Dilettant you are right, PYTHONPATH does not include a path to mysqldb. But it also does not include paths to other modules that work. Do you suggest I add mysqldb path to it?

Comment: Yes. Other modules might be importable due to some magic in the ide, but the path to mysqldb might be only known to you ;-) please also try Pihl's answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17198319/how-to-configure-custom-pythonpath-with-vm-and-pycharm and maybe skim over http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326362/pycharm-and-pythonpath ... it might help

Comment: @Alvin you should choice the right interpreter in **Project Interpreter**. I think, you are using python 2. Try it! P/S: if you want to install, his name is `mysql-python`

Answer (score 3):

As @Dilettant pointed me to https://stackoverflow.com/a/34992894/1989141,
I realised there are two different places I was supposed to set the Python interpreter in PyCharm.

The first is in the main preferences (as in phil’s solution in the link) and allows me to specify a path to a local folder for mysqldb module. 
The second is in the edit configuration settings for the script I want to run. I noticed the interpreters were different.

The script was set to run with the Python 2.7.6 /System/Library/Frameworks/...... version (which I believe is the OSx pre-installed version).
In the terminal and in PyCharm general settings I am using Python 2.7.9 in /usr/local/bin/python.

Matching the script interpreter to the one in the main settings (for which I manyally added mysqldb folder) solves the ImportError. Also I removed the environment variables I set up in the Edit Configuration as they are not needed.

Hope this helps. Thanks to both @Dilettant and @julivico for their suggestions.