# Add directory to Python path in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, pythonpath

I want to be able to use the `paraview.simple` library in PyCharm. I already have paraview installed in my computer. This package cannot be installed with `pip` and there are no .whl files as far as I can tell. The website [docs](https://www.paraview.org/ParaView/Doc/Nightly/www/py-doc/quick-start.html) recommend that the directory containing all the python files be added to PYTHONPATH.

How do I add the relevant folder in PYTHONPATH on my PyCharm session, and keep it there by default, such that when I close out and reopen the `paraview.simple` library is still available?

Comment: If it is installed in your computer, try to reload all the python packages in pycharm

Answer (score 79):

You can add custom paths this way.

- Go to File->Settings->project Interpreter
- In the Project-Interpreter field, click the down facing arrow and select "show All"
- In that Menu, highlight your interpreter and then in the right menu, select the button "Show paths for the selected interpreter" (this is the last button)
- click the plus symbol to add your path

Answer (score 43):

Adding interpreter paths in PyCharm:

1. Project Settings/Project Interpreter: select "settings" icon
2. Project Interpreters: select "tree" icon
3. Interpreter Paths: select "plus" icon

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 12):

In PyCharm version 2020.3.1 use the following workflow instead (see [official docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-project-structure.html)):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> - open Settings.

File|Settings|Project|Project Structure...

You will see project folder structure. Mark subfolders as Sources or Excluded

[image: File|Settings|Project|Project Structure]

Comment: This seems like the most straightforward way to go as of April 2021

Comment: I don't think this works if the external file isn't part of your project. This interface only lets me mark folders that are in my project folder as sources.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. While you could set the environment variable `PYTHONPATH` through other means such as  `.ENV` file or define environment variables in the `Configuration` settings - I have found that doing it using the `Settings --> Project Structure`   dialog (as shown in this answer) imparts more development time intelligence. i.e. PyCharm intellisense can detect your modules and carry out auto-complete, etc.

Answer (score 1):

- Use anaconda with Pycharm
- To install paraview with anaconda run the following command: `conda install -c conda-forge paraview`
- If conda command is not  recognized then register the Anaconda path to environment variable
- Now open pycharm and give the configuration path as the Anaconda path
- File -> Settings -> Project Interpreter
- In Project Interpreter give similar path : "C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\python.exe"

Answer (score 0):

For me this solved it: mapping the local path to the remote inside the Pycharm run configurations settings.

Edit Configurations > Path Mappings >

Local path = /<Users/me/pycharm etc.../project root>
remote path = /

eg.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me, in PyCharm 2022.3.1 the way to do this was different than currently listed (though still similar).

1. Press CTRL+ALT+S to open settings or go through the toolbar via `File -> Settings`
2. Navigate to your `Project` settings, expand, and click "Python Interpreter"
3. Click the drop down to show interpreters, and then click "Show All"
   [image: Example of where the button is]
4. In the resulting popup, select the interpreter you want to add the path to, and then click the folder-tree icon

[image: Toolbar example with folder tree button highlighted]

In the newest pop up modal window you can add paths by clicking the `+` button and navigating to the path you want to include.

[image: Add Path Image]