# Add custom modules to PyCharm Linter

Tags: python, pycharm, gem5

I want to use the PyCharm IDE for developing code in a gem5 project.
With

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/<username>/gem5/src/python/')
import m5
from m5.objects import *
system = System()
```

i tried to import the m5 libraries of gem5 to allow linting within the project.
m5 and everything related to it are not found by PyCharm

```
No Module named m5
```

How can i import this to make full use of the linter?

Comment: I also tried to add those folders to the project, now m5 will be found as a module but everything which should be imported from m5 is not

Comment: I have explained this in more details at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61656340/9160762

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications. I know it might not seem this hard to understand the python part, but i want to make it easier for students to incorporate, as they are struggling with understanding gem5