# Viewing the parameters of the branch predictor in gem5

Tags: branch-prediction, gem5

part question. First, how do I configure the size of a branch predictor?

I can see that I can set the type using the se.py config script and the --bp-type argument. (In my case I'm setting it to LTAGE), but how do I change the size of the tables? And is there an easy way to see the total size of all tables?

My second part, is looking at the code, I don't understand the LTAGE constructor:

```
LTAGE::LTAGE(const LTAGEParams *params)
  : TAGE(params), loopPredictor(params->loop_predictor)
{

}
```

The LTAGEParams doesn't appear to be defined anywhere except here:

```
LTAGE*
LTAGEParams::create()
{
    return new LTAGE(this);
}
```

How can I see what all the members of LTAGEParams are?

Answer (score 1):

About the size, have a look at `m5out/config.ini` after running a simulation, it contains all SimObject parameters.

In the case of branch predictors, all Python-visible parameters of each implemented predictor will be defined in its respective class declaration at `src/cpu/pred/BranchPredictor.py`. They also inherit the parameters of their base class. For example, `LTAGE` has all the parameters of the `TAGE` class - out of which the *tage* object is re-assigned to be an instance of `LTAGE_TAGE` - and a new parameter, *loop_predictor*, which is a `LoopPredictor` instance.

You can then just set any of the values in that file from your Python config and they will be used (double check in `config.ini` after re-running).

The C++ constructor of SimObjects takes a param object like `LTAGEParams` and that object is autogenerated from the corresponding Python SimObject file, and passes values from Python configs to C++ using pybind11.

gem5 has a lot of code generation, so whenever you can't find a definition, grep inside the build directory. This is also why I recommend setting up Eclipse inside the build directory: [How to setup Eclipse IDE for gem5 development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61656709/how-to-setup-eclipse-ide-for-gem5-development/61656710#61656710)

SimObject autogeneration is described further at: https://cirosantilli.com/linux-kernel-module-cheat/#gem5-python-c-interaction

Comment: Giving a heads-up, since I believe you want to incorporate it: the Prefetcher -> BranchPredictor edit got rejected

Comment: @DanielCarvalho a valeu, using that account was an accident, but I thought that would have worked since that account has 2k+ rep. Weird rules.