# Removing paths from PYTHONPATH in PyCharm not working properly?

Tags: python, pycharm, sys, pythonpath

I'm using PyCharm and I need to remove a few paths in my PYTHONPATH just for a specific conda environment that I already have created.

I followed the steps in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326362/pycharm-and-pythonpath/28326635), but instead of pressing plus (+), I pressed minus (-) on the paths I want to remove. After it, it says "removed by the user" in parentheses at the end of the (supposedly) removed paths.

However, when I call:

```
sys.path
```

the paths that sould've been removed are still there.

I tried removing the *.idea* folder of PyCharm, closing the project and creating a new one, but it seems that this option just doesn't work in PyCharm.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The team from IntelliJ replied saying it is indeed a known bug. Here's the link to it:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17969

It's 4 years old, so it doesn't seem it's going to be fixed anytime soon. Upvote it for visibility, if you'd like it fixed.