# Setting PYTHONPATH in PyCharm per project

Tags: python-3.x, path, pycharm

Is it possible to set the PYTHONPATH per project in PyCharm? I do not want to set it as an environment variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyCharm and PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326362/pycharm-and-pythonpath)

Comment: The latest PyCharm does not work like that answer suggests