# How to load saved environment variables in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, environment-variables, conda

I created Python virtual environments using conda. Following [conda user guide](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#macos-and-linux), I added an environment variable in `./etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh`:

```
export PYTHONPATH="~/codes/my_modules:$PYTHONPATH"
```

This allows to import personal modules I saved in `~/codes/my_modules/` and it works fine when I run scripts in the Terminal.

However, if I run my scripts in PyCharm inside the Python Console, it seems that these environment variables are not "loaded" while I configured the correct Python interpreter.

Is there a solution for PyCharm to "load" what is in `./etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh`?

Note: I'd prefer not to configure the environment variables manually in the configuration window of PyCharm. This can be done by following the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28326362/pycharm-and-pythonpath), but I'd prefer if PyCharm could check what's in `./etc/conda/activate.d/env_vars.sh` automatically.
Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you see this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708389/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-pycharm

Comment: Yes, this is what I call configuring the environment variables manually in the configuration window of PyCharm.